# SQL CLR Function Table Input & Output

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, clr

I am new here, and this is my first question.

I've created a dll in VB in order to use it in SQL server 2008 R2 Development

the below example is functional if I remove the table input (and use xml), but I need to have a table input.

--VB--

```
[SqlFunction(DataAccess:=DataAccessKind.Read, FillRowMethodName:="FillRow", TableDefinition:="ID int, Text nvarchar(max)")]
Public Shared Function MyFunction(ByVal tbl As IEnumerable(Of InputRow)) As IEnumerable
...
End Function

Public Shared Sub FillRow(...)
...
End Sub

Public Class InputRow
    Public sID As SqlInt32
    Public sText As SqlString
End Class
```

--SQL--

```
Create ASSEMBLY [ASSEMBLY1] from '[PATH].dll'
WITH PERMISSION_SET = unsafe
CREATE ASSEMBLY [ASSEMBLY2] from '[PATH].XmlSerializers.dll'
WITH PERMISSION_SET = unsafe 

CREATE TYPE TableInput AS TABLE 
(ID int, MyText varchar(1024))

CREATE FUNCTION ufn
(@sInputTable TableInput READONLY)
RETURNS TABLE (
    anID int null, 
    SomeText nvarchar(max) null)
        WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS EXTERNAL NAME MyDotNETAssembly.[MyNamespace.MyClassname].MyFunction
```

Error:
Msg 6552, Level 16, State 3, Procedure ufn, Line 2
CREATE FUNCTION for "ufn" failed because T-SQL and CLR types for parameter "@sInputTable" do not match.

Can anyone help?
how do I "assign" the input parameter in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

In your CLR function, you should specify that ID and Text allow nulls such as `TableDefinition:="ID int null, Text nvarchar(max) null"`.

You should also make sure that the column names match up with your InputRow class definition. To make it easier, I'd just ensure that the names are the same throughout. That is, change `ID` and `sID` to `anID`, `Text` and `sText` to `SomeText`.